# Google logs explorer query with advanced operations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

our project has Google logging. While troubleshooting on Google's logs explorer console from the browser, we sometimes need to identify which of our database queries took longer than expected. So, for that, I am looking for some operation that filters out the logs that exceed the expected time.

Below is a sample log which getting logged on Google Logs:

```
{
  "textPayload": "LOG:  execute",
  "resource": {
    "type": "k8s_container"
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-07-23T03:44:52.638577973Z",
  "logName": "sample/project",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-07-23T03:44:52.972653990Z"
}
```

Now, what I found out is a query something like below :

```
timestamp = "2023-07-23T03:23:05.690692065Z" AND receiveTimestamp >= "2023-07-23T03:23:10.941393777Z"
```

But this is still not up to the mark as in this the `timestmap` parameter should be strict to a specific time and that might be unsure because it might differ by some seconds and milliseconds. Even `receiveTimestamp` is also can not be defined as a hard-coded value because that will very hard and time-consuming operation where we have to put some value and check relevant logs.

What I am looking for is something where I can able to find the gap between that two parameters and then I can apply some threshold to get filter the relevant logs. Below is just an example,

`receiveTimestamp - timestamp > threshold/gap of time`

Any kind of help and guidance would be appreciated. Not sure if Google logs explorer supports this kind of operation as well, if any alternatives exist that would be also preferred.

Comment: Did you have a look to the log analytics feature? It could solve your issue. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/log-analytics#analytics

Comment: Thanks for the response @guillaumeblaquiere. But that will change my current logging system.

Comment: I agree, it's another API and way to query the logs, but it's more powerful and versatile. You can bet on it for the future, you will able able to do more!

Comment: Agree with you and thanks for the suggestion. Not sure our team is ready to change that implementation. @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: @Ronak Joshi, Have you tried the log analytics feature suggested by guillaumeblaquiere  and the issue is resolved?